# Palette not returning the correct length?

Tags: r

The following in R doesn't work as expected:

```
Dummy <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
length(palette(rainbow(length(Dummy))))
[1] 8
length(palette(rainbow(length(Dummy))))
[1] 6
length(palette(rainbow(length(Dummy))))
[1] 6
```

Why?

Comment: Thanks Marco. It's very odd, for now I have to run palette(rainbow(length(Dummy))) twice to avoid the error. Will see if I can get to the bottom of it report findings here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `palette` with an argument the main thing it does is a side-effect: it changes the palette that is in effect.  The other thing it does is it returns the palette that was in effect prior to calling `palette` (from `?palette`):

> Value:
>
> A character vector giving the palette which *was* in effect.  This
>        is 'invisible' unless the argument is omitted.

So, in your case, the first time you call `palette(...)`, `palette` returns the default color palette (of length 8) *and* sets the active palette to be the new one.  The next time you call it it returns the palette you set previously.